# How to select a line in a RichTextBox on a mouse click?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a read-only RichTextBox in my user interface.  I want to make it so that when I click on a line of text with the mouse it selects or highlights the entire line.  Just that one line that was clicked.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RichTextBox has all the methods you need, you just need multiple of them.  First you need to map the mouse position to a character index:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim box = DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox)
    Dim index = box.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)
```

Then you need to map the character index to a line:

```
    Dim line = box.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
```

Then you need to find out where the line starts:

```
    Dim lineStart = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line)
```

Then you need to find out where it ends, which is the start of the next line minus one:

```
    Dim lineEnd = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) - 1
```

Then you need to make the selection:

```
    box.SelectionStart = lineStart
    box.SelectionLength = lineEnd - lineStart
```

Summarizing:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseDown
    Dim box = DirectCast(sender, RichTextBox)
    Dim index = box.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)
    Dim line = box.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
    Dim lineStart = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line)
    Dim lineEnd = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) - 1
    box.SelectionStart = lineStart
    box.SelectionLength = lineEnd - lineStart
End Sub
```

Comment: If you select the last line in the textbox it will cause an error since the lineEnd is -2

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code in click event handler

```
SendKeys.Send("{HOME}+{END}")
```

Comment: I dont want to select all, I just want to highlight the line i click.