# RichTextBox On click Select the Line below

Tags: .net, select, click, richtextbox

How do I select the line below the one I click on? 
So far I have this [How to select a line in a RichTextBox on a mouse click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746121/richtextbox-select-line-on-click)
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is to your second question i.e. :  how do I assign this selection to a variable? :| I need to assign selected line to X and line below to Y.

```
    private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox = ((RichTextBox)sender);

        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}+{END}");
        SendKeys.Flush();

        string X = richTextBox.SelectedText;

        SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}+{END}");
        SendKeys.Flush();

        string Y = richTextBox.SelectedText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");//Move cursor to next line
   SendKeys.Send("{HOME}+{END}");//Select the line
}
```

Comment: how do I assign this selection to a variable? :| I need to assign selected line to X and line below to Y.